# Multiple instances of objects using the same function as the newest instance

Tags: javascript, closures

I encountered this issue when creating a function for a Javascript library. As far as I can tell, when an object's function uses a combination of a closure and a promise, the most recently created version would be used for all instances. The output of the below code is "3" repeated three times. However, when I add `var` in front of the line defining `logSecret`, the output is then 1 2 3, which is what I originally expected.

Why do multiple instances of the object end up using the same value?

Why does adding `var` in front of the closure fix the issue?

Unfortunately I don't know Javascript quite well enough to understand what exactly is happening here, so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what is happening here. Thank you!

```js
function MyObject(myValue){
  var _this = this;
  _this.secret = myValue;
  _this.foo = function() {
    makePromise = function() {
      var promise = $.Deferred();
      promise.resolve("done");
      return promise;
    }
    logSecret = function() {
      console.log(_this.secret);
    }

    var promise = makePromise();
    $.when(promise).then(function (data) { logSecret(); });
  }
}

var obj1 = new MyObject(1);
var obj2 = new MyObject(2);
var obj3 = new MyObject(3);
obj1.foo();
obj2.foo();
obj3.foo();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Without `var`, `logSecret` is a **global** variable. Same goes for `makePromise`. Variables should **always** be explicitly declared.

Comment: Make sure to always use strict mode, so that these mistakes don't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In non-strict mode, when variables are not explicitly declared with `var`, `let` or `const`, an implicit global variable is created. ie. such variables behave as if they had been declared in the global context.

In your code, the variables `makePromise` and `logSecret` are not explicitly declared and so are shared by every invocation of `MyObject`.

So, every time `MyObject` is invoked, the `makePromise` and `logSecret` are overwritten with a new function object instance that closes over the lexical environment for the latest invocation of `MyObject`.

The final invocation of `MyObject` closes over the secret value of `3`, hence the observed behavior.

```js
function MyObject(myValue) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.secret = myValue;
    _this.foo = function() {
        makePromise = function() { // global variable
            var promise = $.Deferred();
            promise.resolve("done");
            return promise;
        }

        logSecret = function() { // global variable
            console.log(_this.secret);
        }

        var promise = makePromise();
        $.when(promise).then(function(data) {
            logSecret();
        });
    }
}
```